# SQL Statement Syntax Differences WHERE AND

Tags: sql, sql-server

Two syntaxes return same results and introduce same Actual Execution Plan in SQL Server:

Example 1:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(c.ID), pID FROM Table1 t1       
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    WHERE %some_contition%;
```

Example 2:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(c.ID), pID FROM Table1 t1       
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    AND %some_contition%;
```

Is there any performance differences on large tables ? Any other concern when using this or that syntax ? Please elaborate if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Both queries should produce same execution plan.

Comment: @Fabio They do as written in question :)